# Dividing inpustream into two streams

Tags: java, inputstream

I needed to combine to inpustreams, which one has only `string` and the other one is an `avi` file. I can easily combine two of them like below:

> InputStream is = new SequenceInputStream(stringStream, aviStream);

However, when it comes to take the string and the avi separately, I am failing. The avi file does not match to its first size and somehow I am losing some size.

I can read `is` with a `Scanner` by using a `delimiter`, but in that case the avi stream will be `String` and i will lose information.

Any idea how can I separate the inputstream? I want to read back my string and i should have the rest of the stream as an inpustream.

**EDIT**: I am thinking of converting the stream to a byte array, then divide the array into two according to the delimiter. Then second part, which is the avi one, i can convert it back to an inputstream. But it seems to troublesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Scanner is only for text data, not binary. Binary data e.g. AVI can contain every byte value which means there is no delimiter you can use which will not appear in the data.

You can combine text with raw data in the following manner.

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(...);
dos.writeUTF(string);
dos.writeInt(bytes.length);
dos.write(bytes);
```

to reverse the process you can use DataInputStream with readUTF, readInt and readFully()

Comment: So you are saying if i call readUtf it will give me only strings, but how am i supposed to read the avi? I supposed readFully reads all?

Comment: You read the length your wrote with `readInt`, create a `byte[]` of that size and call readFully on that byte array.

Comment: You can use this approach to combine any combination of text and binary.  Note: for large blocks of date you may what to read/write them in smaller blocks e.g. 8 KB rather than one massive `byte[]`  If your size can be more then 2 GB you can use writeLong/readLong.

Comment: cheers, works like a charm. currently dealing with small files, but will consider your word

Comment: You can send any number of files this way as well as additional data. .e.g the modification date of the file.